# When build with py2app can't save in folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2app

When I build a python script with py2app they don't save text files in a folder. On IDLE working normally

```
name = first_name() + ' ' + last_name()
save_path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/Folder')
name_of_file = name
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file + ".txt")

with open(completeName, 'w') as f:
    print('1st line', file=f)
```

Comment: Your code does not save anything.

Comment: @KlausD. this is for print in a file and working with IDLE, but not working when I create .app

with open(completeName, 'w') as f:
    print('1st line', file=f)

Comment: You should add all relevant information, especially code, to the question itself.